# Unable to set NFT tokenURI with web3py

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python, nft

I have the following contract method:

```
    function setTokenURI(uint256 tokenid, string memory uri) public {
        require(bytes(uri).length != 0, "Cannot set an empty URI");
        _setTokenURI(tokenid, uri);
    }
```

and when I call it from my web3py script:

```
contract.functions.setTokenURI(token, "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/2jh2kl3j4h23jk4h2").call()
```

I don't get any errors, but the URI is not set.  I run other functions against the contract with the web3py interface and they all work as expected.

Why would this call not update the NFT tokenURI?

Comment: Writing functions on blockchain requires gas, are you sending gas cost ?

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: instead of using `contract.functions.setURI(...).call()`, use `contract.functions.setURI.transact()`

There's a big difference between how web3 libraries call a read-only function and how they call a state-changing function. For the former, no value needs to be sent, nothing needs to be signed with a private key. When state is being changed, though, a transaction is made. Changing the state requires sending ether over the network to pay for gas, which requires forming a transaction signed by a private key.

These two ways of interacting with the chain are reflected by the two different suffixes you can use with web3.py: `call()` and `transact()`. `call()` is used for reading data from the chain (`view` or `pure` functions), whereas `transact()` is used for state-changing functions.

Depending on your web3.py setup, you may need to add details to your `transact()` call. `transact()` can take an object as an argument in which you can specify what address the tx should originate from, the amount of ether being sent, etc. The docs for `transact()` are [here](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.ContractFunction.transact), and the docs for what you can put in the object arg are [here](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.send_transaction) (the object follows the format of a `transaction` object, which is outlined there).

Hope that helps!